# Retrieving values from a hash map in my JSP

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

Some background information of what I'm trying to achieve is a user hits the submit button on my JSP page it needs to send the message submitted to a text file and then I need to access the file and retrieve all the messages in the file in my JSP page.  Please help me out, I have spent too long and I'm not sure what I need to do to be able to iterate over the hash map to show all the messages.

This is what my code looks like right now:

Controller:

```
public class TwitServlet extends HttpServlet {

@Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request,
    HttpServletResponse response)
    throws ServletException, IOException {

    String twits = "";
    String path = getServletContext().getRealPath("/WEB-INF/twit.txt");
    HttpSession session = request.getSession();

    String tweet = request.getParameter("tweet");

    System.out.print(tweet);
    String usern = (String) session.getAttribute("user");
    String alias = (String) session.getAttribute("uname");

    twitDB.insert(tweet, usern, alias, path);

    Map test = twitDB.getTwit("/Users/emilio/Desktop/twit.txt");



    session.setAttribute("test",test);

    getServletContext()
    .getRequestDispatcher("/home.jsp").forward(request, response);
}
```

}

Database(using txtfile for now):

```
ublic class twitDB {

public static void insert (String twit, String user, String uname, String path) throws IOException {

    Date date = new Date();
    SimpleDateFormat ft = new SimpleDateFormat ("yyyy/MM/dd");
    String dateString = ft.format(date);
    File file = new File ("/Users/emilio/Desktop/twit.txt");
    try ( PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter(file,    true))){

        out.println("[@"+uname+"]:" + " " + dateString);
        out.println(user); 
        out.println(twit);
        out.println(".");
        out.close();
    }
    catch (IOException iox) {
        //do stuff with exception
        iox.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public static Map<String,Tweet> getTwit(String filename) throws IOException {
    Map<String,Tweet> tweets = new HashMap<String,Tweet>();
    File file = new File ("/Users/emilio/Desktop/twit.txt");
    Scanner in = new Scanner(file);

    while (in.hasNextLine()) {
        String uname = in.nextLine();
        String name = in.nextLine();
        String twit = in.nextLine();
       String filler = in.nextLine();
       Tweet tweet = new Tweet(uname, name, twit);

        tweets.put(uname, tweet);
        tweets.put(name, tweet);
        tweets.put(twit,tweet );

    }
    in.close();
    return tweets;
    }


   }
```

Part of my JSP:

```
 <button type="submit" method="post" class="btn btn-twitter">
                                                        <span   class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"/>Tweet
                                                        </button>
                                                    </div>

                                                </form>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class = "row feed">
                                        <p>

                            <c:forEach items="${test}" var="test">

                        </c:forEach>

                                        </p>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing tag to do print if you are really getting data from the server.

```
<c:forEach items="${test}" var="test">
  <c:out value="${test}"/> 
</c:forEach>
```

Comment: Thanks for the input. It shows up like this for some reason :  tweeting to test=business.Tweet@f01f5e7 tweet tweet=business.Tweet@172f4335 tweet again=business.Tweet@3e449c13 Hiii=business.Tweet@6f807472         Any idea why it could be doing this.